# Enterprise mode forced on preventing site working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking to release a website on a company network, they force enable Enterprise mode (use IE11). My understanding is turning on Enterprise mode renders the browser as IE8.

The website is not working now the enterprise Mode is on

Ive tried changing the mega tag to:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

I have also tried to connecting to older versions of JQuery as I believe anything from IE 8 and below is not supported from version 2.0.0 onwards.

I am kind of lost as to whay I cant get this working and any help is hugely appreciated

My HTML:

```
<div style="font-size:10px" class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'SafetyCheck')">CLICK ME</button>
</div>

<div id="SafetyCheck" class="tabcontent">
<!--  <h3 class="headers">Check Form</h3>-->
            <iframe id="formbuilderiframe" src="http://127.0.0.1/Form.asp" style="height:590;"></iframe> 
</div>
```

My Jquery:

```
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");

// Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

// Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

// Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

This is my CSS:

```
  /* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid RGB(0,70,135);
 /*   border: 1px solid #ccc; */
  background-color: #f1f1f1; 
  /*width:76%;
  margin-left:1% */

}

/* Style the buttons that are used to open the tab content */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit; 
  float: left;
  border: 0px solid RGB(0,70,135);
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;

}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: RGB(125,194,66);
/*  background-color: #ddd; */
 }

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
```

In the code I've provided, when someone clicks a menu button a div becomes unhidden and displays an iFrame, however clicking the menu does nothing (but works fine when Enterprise Mode is disabled)

Comment: Please edit question since a. this is not jquery, b. you haven't posted css (c.you just copy-paste w3schools exapmple).

Comment: Yes they are W3schools code which I have put in to the website, which works fine without Enterprise Mode enabled

Comment: Try this https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim

Comment: There is no jQuery in your code, it's only javascript. Also edit your question to put the CSS code at the CSS place.

Comment: To confirm, to try it I can just add the <script> tags at the bottom of that link to my home.asp? If so I have just tried that to no avail. Many thanks